# dynamic controls not populating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple user control that will be displayed numerous times on the page. So i have a panel which a loop over a dataset, creating the UC, populating a textbox and a checkbox, and then adding it to the panel.

The panel adds the UC but neither the textbox value nor the checkbox is changed...

```
foreach (Issue iss in Case.Issues)
{
    Comments comment = (Comments)LoadControl("~/UserControls/Comments.ascx");
    comment .ID = "Comment" + iss.IssueDetail.quality_control_issue_id.ToString();
    comment .Populate(iss);
    QCComments_list.Controls.Add(comment );
}
```

Do i have to do this on pre-render or Onit of the page or there a way of refreshing the controls of the UC?

Here's the UC markup. very simple.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ROI_Comments.ascx.cs" Inherits="QualityControl_UserControls.ROI_Comments" %>
<!-- Field -->
    <div id="ROI_Comment_DIV" class="field">
        <label>Corrections</label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="comtxt" name="comtxt"  />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="issue_critical" runat="server" Text="Critical" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="SaveButton" Text="Add Comment" OnClientClick="SaveComment(this);return false;"  />
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="ROICancelButton" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return false;"  />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hIssueID" />
    </div>
    <!-- /Field -->
```

and the .cs

```
 public partial class ROI_Comments : System.Web.UI.UserControl
        {
            public ROI_Comments()
            {

            }

            public void Populate(cQuality_Control_Issue _comment)
            {
                try
                {
                    hIssueID.Value = _comment.IssueDetail.quality_control_issue_id.ToString();
                    comtxt.Value = _comment.IssueDetail.quality_control_issue_description;
                    comtxt.Disabled = true;
                    issue_critical.Checked = _comment.IssueDetail.quality_control_issue_critical;
                    issue_critical.Enabled = false;
                    ROICancelButton.Text = "Delete";

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you show us the code and the mark-up of the UserControl?

Comment: done. its only a small UC

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong from what you have shown but there could be a null reference exception occurring before the values are set. You would not know about it because of the empty try/catch block. Its never a good idea to use an empty try/catch because you would have no idea if an exception is occurring.

Comment: Yes of course you're right about the try catch - its in development at the moment. But overriding OnInit has done the trick.

So now i call the function that adds the UC's before i call base.Oninit(e).